# Error while deploying Spring MVC application on Tomcat 8

Tags: spring, tomcat

I need to deploy a Spring MVC application on Tomcat 8 but I am getting 404 error with the following description

```
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

In Intellij it shows NullPointerException error. Now I am running from the terminal but I get error when I try to deploy and run it on Tomcat8 server. I checked the log file for Tomcat and it shows the following:

```
24-Feb-2019 00:28:59.083 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/twulams.war]
24-Feb-2019 00:29:02.214 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
24-Feb-2019 00:29:03.981 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
24-Feb-2019 00:29:03.991 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/twulams] startup failed due to previous errors
24-Feb-2019 00:29:04.025 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [twulams] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
24-Feb-2019 00:29:04.027 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:41)
24-Feb-2019 00:29:04.034 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/twulams.war] has finished in [4,951] ms
```

**catalina.out**

```
24-Feb-2019 00:59:06.809 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/twulams]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:46.854 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/twulams.war]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
24-Feb-2019 01:01:50.628 INFO [Thread-7] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:50.680 INFO [Thread-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:50.681 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
 java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:418)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1362)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.380 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.383 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/twulams] startup failed due to previous errors
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.414 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [twulams] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.415 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:41)
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.416 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsxa17q3yp5l6hqia|182ba3b5]-AdminTaskTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:553)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.417 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsxa17q3yp5l6hqia|182ba3b5]-HelperThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:635)
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.417 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsxa17q3yp5l6hqia|182ba3b5]-HelperThread-#1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:635)
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.418 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsxa17q3yp5l6hqia|182ba3b5]-HelperThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:635)
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.422 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/twulams.war] has finished in [6,568] ms
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.439 INFO [Thread-7] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:53.444 INFO [Thread-7] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.384 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.396 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.396 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.397 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.399 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.400 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.401 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.401 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.402 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.402 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.402 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:54.403 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.232 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.30 (Ubuntu)
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.233 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 13 2018 20:23:56 UTC
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.233 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.30.0
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.15.0-45-generic
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.235 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.235 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.237 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /var/lib/tomcat8
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.237 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.239 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.239 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.242 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.242 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.242 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.242 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.243 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.243 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.244 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.244 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.244 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.245 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version [1.6.3].
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.245 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.246 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.251 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.313 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.340 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.354 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 884 ms
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.30 (Ubuntu)
24-Feb-2019 01:01:55.513 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/twulams.war]
24-Feb-2019 01:01:58.858 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration (logging only errors to the console), or user programmatically provided configurations. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j 2 internal initialization logging. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for instructions on how to configure Log4j 2
24-Feb-2019 01:02:04.421 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
24-Feb-2019 01:02:04.434 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/twulams] startup failed due to previous errors
24-Feb-2019 01:02:04.467 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [twulams] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
24-Feb-2019 01:02:04.468 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:41)
24-Feb-2019 01:02:04.468 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsxa17q46qv8v9k33|5760c02c]-AdminTaskTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:553)
 java.base@10.0.2/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
24-Feb-2019 01:02:04.469 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsxa17q46qv8v9k33|5760c02c]-HelperThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:635)
24-Feb-2019 01:02:04.469 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsxa17q46qv8v9k33|5760c02c]-HelperThread-#1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:635)
24-Feb-2019 01:02:04.470 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [twulams] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsxa17q46qv8v9k33|5760c02c]-HelperThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10.0.2/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:635)
24-Feb-2019 01:02:04.479 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/twulams.war] has finished in [8,965] ms
24-Feb-2019 01:02:04.480 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
24-Feb-2019 01:02:05.040 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [560] ms
24-Feb-2019 01:02:05.046 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
24-Feb-2019 01:02:05.072 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 9716 ms
```

I have added the latest log from Catalina.out file. Can anyone tell me how to debug the error? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you enable your application log such that it print out more useful information ?

Comment: Can you tell me how to enable application log? I am new to Spring MVC and Tomcat. So I do not have much idea about that.